# After exporting a PDF from Illustrator, it opens as a different size in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, pdf

I have an image that I created in Illustrator and need to work with in Photoshop.

The size of the artboard in Illustrator is 240cm width x 360cm height.

I export to PDF, however when I open it in Photoshop, the size of the document is 240cm width x 270.9 height.

Please see the attached pictures.

What could the reason for this be?

[image: Photoshop]
[image: Illustrator]

Comment: It might help if you were able to give a link to the file (dropbox) and we could check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a workaround. Have in Photoshop a blank image with the needed pixel dimensions. 100 inches and 300 pixels/inch with 16 bits/color/pixel would freeze my ancient equipment immediately, but hopefully you have something modern and effective. If not, you should reduce the resolution.

Copy and paste the original image from Illustrator to Photoshop. You have a possiblity to adjust the scaling and select do you want a bitmap (=pixels), paths or a smart object.

I bet you in this phase need the bitmap, otherwise the whole trip in PS is unclear. Considering this right, you can as well rasterize the image in Illustrator with the needed resolution, save as PSD, PNG, TIF or JPG and open it in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

When opening in Photoshop be certain to set the **Crop To** option correctly.

[image]

You most likely want `Media` or `Trim` - which will be the artboard size. Or you may want `Bleed` to include any bleed area in AI.

Comment: I've tried with all the options. All of them do the same thing.